# Change width and height of image without cropping it

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to change the width and height of the image tag in angularjs, but the following crops the image instead of re-sizing it. I tried the ng-image-resize but in vain.

```
ng-src="{{imageInfo.DecachedImageUrl}}" style="width:380px ; height:295px"
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, nor do I see what you've tried. Why aren't you simply changing the style property's value?

Comment: that won't crop anything unless the container is set to `overflow:hidden` or something similar. Please provide all relevant code and preferrably a demo that replicates problem

Comment: try to create a div around your img, with both dimensions, and on img, use only width or height.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same in HTML as with angular. Simply use the width/height attributes instead of style.

```
ng-src="{{imageInfo.DecachedImageUrl}}" width="380px" height="295px"
```